# ruby csv add single quotes to a particular column

Tags: ruby, csv

I am using Ruby csv library and I was wondering how I can add single quotes to a particular column.

Example row: `1,56,"James",Finland`

Say I want to add the quotes on `Finland`

Comment: Those look like double quotes.

Comment: For what do you need it? I'm thinking of using a converter, but thats possible for specific data, not specific columns.

Comment: I am doing it for data I have in a csv file for specifically a date field which does not have quotes around it.

Comment: @paguardiario for that field I want `single` quotes

Answer (score 0):

try something like

First Read the CSV and pull all rows in a array

```
  arr = []
  CSV.foreach('test.csv') {|row|  arr << row }
```

Then with the array pull the column that you want to keep in double quotes

```
  arr.each do |row|
  column_value = row[3] #I am assuming i am editing the second column
  row[3].replace("'" + "#{column_value}" + "'")
  end
```

then write back to the file

```
 CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  arr.each {|row| csv << row }
end
```

Comment: The CSV already exist and I want to modify a particular column

Comment: I had to alter this line: `CSV.foreach('test.csv') {|row|  arr << row` } to: `CSV.foreach('test.csv',encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8'){|row| arr << row }` as I was getting some encoding problems but now the fields that are already in quotes are losing the quotes.

Comment: @mpora, i think your CSV has some french or latin characters.. can you help me in giving some of those characters maybe i will alter my solution thn

Comment: Apparently there are no special characters, I dont know why it was complaining. What is bothering me now is because I am losing quotes on other columns when I write back to the file.

Comment: Or it might be complaining about `-` and `&`